# How to share In-App purchase data between two iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, icloud

I want to share In-App purchased product identifiers from one app(say "App1") to another app(say "App2"). Both run on iOS 7 devices. And more importantly since "App2" was released long time back, both the apps have **different Team IDs.** When the user clicks on a "Restore purchase from App1" button I want "App2" to unlock certain features based on the purchases the user has made in "App1". What is the best way to achieve this?

- I dont want to use UIDocumentInteractionController or UIActivityViewController because that would require unnecessary user interaction.
- Key chain items or iCloud key-value storage cannot be shared because both the apps have different Team IDs.
- Can't use an exclusive server through which the two apps can communicate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by using the IAP API. You could store the information on your server and unlock it for a user, however, **this is against the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)**:

```
Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected.
```

And technically you would not be using the API if you checked against your own server and provided the content through that.

Comment: I have to use the IAP API. I can get the list of all products purchased in "App1" by reading the file at [NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL]. The real question is how do I send this list(which is an array of NSStrings btw) from "App1" to "App2". I can't use custom URL either. It could be easy to hack!

Comment: Right, technically you could achieve it. BUT it is against App Store Review Guidelines. If you submit an app with this kind of functionality you risk getting in trouble and your apps pulled.

Comment: "And technically you would not be using the API if you checked against your own server and provided the content through that." NO See https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html "Your app is responsible for making subscriptions available across all the user’s devices after they’re purchased and for letting users restore past purchases. For example, most subscriptions are provided by a server; your server would need some mechanism to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user who purchased them."

Answer (score 0):

Now this looks possible for subscriptions with App Bundles: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_a_subscription_across_multiple_apps

> You can offer customers auto-renewable subscription services that are accessible through multiple apps across one or more operating systems.
>
> In order to offer this functionality, your server must grant access to the subscription content across all apps, despite the user having purchased the subscription within a specific app. You can use a unified account management database along with server-side receipt validation to validate a user's purchase and ensure in-app transactions are handled. By entitling subscription access from your server, you can provide users the ability to access your subscription across multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible using Authentication API
step 1: When purchased product successfully to store status inside API
step 2: Then call API  every time of didFinishLaunching to check purchase status and use multiple APP

Another benefit is make payment without any payment gateway...